# How to Customize the category list page

Tags: categories

i use evolve theme for my site.
here is the screenshot of category list

[image]

the page display the raw code of the page content which contains a gallery.

How can i customize the category display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress determines which template file to use from its [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). It might be further customized by extensions and themes might be using different files for same things, depending on what they do.

There are helper plugins for simpler cases (for example [What The File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/)), but it might require involved debug with more complex themes.

Comment: What I cannot understand is: my theme allows me to configure  a page what is used for the homepage adding some Widget. Can I easily use the same mechanism to configure the page of the Category?

Comment: @Revious that's likely completely implemented by your theme, you should ask its developers/support about possibilities.

Comment: It would be wonderful but they don't give any support. The theme is rush from themeforest, I don't know where to start from..